# A session factory has already been configured with the key of nhibernate.current_session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, s#arp-architecture

NOTE: I posted this on sharp architecture google groups also.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: SharpArch.Core.PreconditionException: A session
factory has already been configured with the key of
nhibernate.current_session

Source Error:

Line 49:             base.Init();
Line 50:
Line 51:             NHibernateSession.Init(new WebSessionStorage
(this),
Line 52:                 new string[] { Server.MapPath("~/bin/
GCBA.Data.dll") });
Line 53:         }

Source File: C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\Matt\GCBA\GCBA\GCBA.Web
\Global.asax.cs    Line: 51

Stack Trace:

[PreconditionException: A session factory has already been configured
with the key of nhibernate.current_session]

SharpArch.Core.Check.Require(Boolean assertion, String message) in
C:\MyStuff\Projects\SharpArchitecture\src\SharpArch\SharpArch.Core
\DesignByContract.cs:62

SharpArch.Data.NHibernate.NHibernateSession.Init(ISessionStorage
storage, String[] mappingAssemblies, AutoPersistenceModel
autoPersistenceModel, String cfgFile, IDictionary`2 cfgProperties,
String validatorCfgFile, IPersistenceConfigurer persistenceConfigurer)
in C:\MyStuff\Projects\SharpArchitecture\src\SharpArch\SharpArch.Data
\NHibernate\NHibernateSession.cs:70

SharpArch.Data.NHibernate.NHibernateSession.Init(ISessionStorage
storage, String[] mappingAssemblies) in C:\MyStuff\Projects
\SharpArchitecture\src\SharpArch\SharpArch.Data\NHibernate
\NHibernateSession.cs:26

GCBA.Web.MvcApplication.Init() in C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\Matt\GCBA
\GCBA\GCBA.Web\Global.asax.cs:51

System.Web.HttpApplication.InitInternal(HttpContext context,
HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers) +335

---

This is the error I get trying to run from IIS7... I can run fine it
seems out of VS2008 Cassini....  So I'm not certain what the issue
is,  I have the 7/16/2009 trunk build of S#arp and MVC.Net 1.0.  The
piece of code it is failing on is in the global.asax.cs Init()
method.  I really am pretty frustrated with this issue, because I have
only found one other post concerning this, and it was in test cases,
where as mine is actually trying to run the website from iis7 and all
my tests pass fine.

If anyone has any idea what may be causing this issue, that would be
great, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same problem. I used S#arp arch but used a normal asp.net website project (integrated in a cms). The whole problem for me was that Global.asax does not trigger on unknown filetypes or virtual urls. I solved it by writing my own HttpModule and loading it separately, this has the side-effect that NHibernate is initiated even though someone is only fetching an image. but for me it wasn´t an issue.

Hopefully that puts you in the right direction...

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like IIS7 is not configured properly for ASP.NET MVC. [See if this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157988/best-way-to-deploy-an-asp-net-mvc-app-on-iis-7-server-2008) helps you in setting up IIS7 with ASP.NET MVC. I'm also using SharpArchitecture and after having IIS7 run in "integrated" mode, solved a bunch of issues.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a threading issue?

Have you tried something like this in your app initialisation:

```
private static bool haveInit
if (!haveInit)
{
    lock (@lock)
    {
        if (!haveInit))
        {
            NHibernateSession.Init(...);
            haveInit = true;
        }
    }
}
```